# Declaring and using matrixes on bash

Tags: arrays, bash, matrix

I'm trying to use a matrix to print some elements generating a matrix in ***Slackware***. First, I **print the matrix while generating it**. Then I **print it**, after that i **change the element on [5,5]** and then **printing it** again.

```
#!/bin/bash
MW=10
MH=10

function Inic {
   for (( i=0 ; i<$MH ; i++ )) do
      for (( j=0 ; j<$MW ; j++ )) do
         MATRIX[${i},${j}]="$i$j" ;
         printf "${MATRIX[$i,$j]} " ;
      done
      printf "\n" ;
   done
   printf "\n" ;
}

function Print {
   for (( Imp=0 ; Imp<$MH ; Imp++ )) do
      for (( Jmp=0 ; Jmp<$MW ; Jmp++ )) do
         printf "${MATRIX[$Imp,$Jmp]} " ;
      done
      echo
   done
   printf "\n"
}

Inic;

Print;

MATRIX[5,5]='**'

Print;
```

the problem is that when i run the script, it shows me this:

```
00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 
20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 
30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 
40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 
50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 
60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 
70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 
80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 
90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 

90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 

90 91 92 93 94 ** 96 97 98 99 
90 91 92 93 94 ** 96 97 98 99 
90 91 92 93 94 ** 96 97 98 99 
90 91 92 93 94 ** 96 97 98 99 
90 91 92 93 94 ** 96 97 98 99 
90 91 92 93 94 ** 96 97 98 99 
90 91 92 93 94 ** 96 97 98 99 
90 91 92 93 94 ** 96 97 98 99 
90 91 92 93 94 ** 96 97 98 99 
90 91 92 93 94 ** 96 97 98 99
```

why does it only keep the last row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MATRIX` is an ordinary, indexed array. That means that the index in

```
MATRIX[$i,$j]
```

is evaluated in an aritmetic context, where `$i, $j` uses the comma operator that evaluates to its right-hand operand. What you want to use to is an associative array, which treats its index as an arbitrary string,

```
declare -A MATRIX
```

`Inic` appears to work because you print each matrix cell before it can be overwritten by another entry.

Answer (score 1):

Because (1) `bash` only has 1-dimensional arrays, and (2) a `[...]` index is evaluated as an arithmetic expression, and (3) a comma-separated list of arithmetic expressions evaluates to the last expression.  Thus `MATRIX[5,5]` is the same as `MATRIX[71,22,33,94,5]`, which is the same as `MATRIX[5]`.

You *can* however use `MATRIX[$i * $MW + $j]` instead of `MATRIX[$i, $j]`.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do with your matrix, this is probably a better idea than using an associative array.